# What do you think of the tenses here?

Tags: grammar

“If I had to explain to a foreigner why Yamamoto’s action was a problem,” Miyadai said, “I don’t think I could do it.”[Source](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2013/12/07/national/emperors-apparent-liberal-leanings-jar-with-japans-right-wing/)

the "was" of "why Yamatomo's action was a problem."

Is it fair to say that this has two possible interpretations, that is, it is purely past and that it is because of the sequence of tenses due to the hypothetical mood of the clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are puzzled by the use of *was*, then it might be easier to understand it outside the context of a relative sentence.

In ‘I had to explain to a foreigner why Yamamoto’s action **was** a problem’, the clause that begins with *why* is in effect reported speech (or, in functional grammar terms, a projected clause). In explaining the situation to the foreigner, the speaker’s actual words would have been something like ‘I have to explain to you why Yamamoto’s action **is** a problem.’ When speech gets reported to someone else, verbs in the present tense generally go into the past tense, and that is what is happening here.

Comment: I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> is it purely past?

No. If it was past perfect/past conditionl, it would read more like this way:

> “If *I'd had* to explain to a foreigner why Yamamoto’s action was a problem,” Miyadai said, “I don’t think I could *have done* it.

The statement is a conditional in which the if clause is in simple past but the main clause is in the present conditional:

> “If I *had* to explain to a foreigner why Yamamoto’s action was a problem,” Miyadai said, “I *don’t think* I could do it.”

You can read more about if and the conditional [here](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/if_conditional1.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's the conditional present that usually uses past verbs to describe a hypothetical situation in the present. For example,

> If I were you, I'd see a doctor.  *I am not you, but I am just giving you a piece of advice.*
>
> If ate that, I could die. *I won't eat that thing to avoid the risk of dying*
>
> If I had his number, I'd call him. *I don't have his number that's why I am not going to call him, because I cannot.*

Comment: However, the sequence of tenses is very randomly applied in journalism.

Comment: @kih1930 It depends on what you mean by "journalism." Native speakers in most cases would use the proper forms if the situation required. In most cases you interview people where they need to say whatever they want to say. Some news outlets might report that verbatim.

Comment: "justing give" instead of "just giving"?

Comment: @PeterShor Fixed it. But it took me a while to find it:)